# Unity: Knockback my player along the Y-axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't think the Y-axis for my code is working. Iv'e tried increasing the yForceToAdd and the localScale.y but (when I collide with the object that has this script attached to it) my player only goes (when I collide at the top of the object) X=1, Y=1 or X=-1, Y=1 and not X=0, Y=1 as well. the same problem with the bottom of my object X=0, Y=-1 doesn't seem to work either. can someone help with this problem?

```
public float xForceToAdd;
public float yForceToAdd;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        //Store the vector 2 of the location where the initial hit happened;
        Vector2 initialHitPoint = new Vector2(other.gameObject.transform.position.x, other.gameObject.transform.position.y);
        float xForce = 0;
        float yForce = 0;

        //Grab our collided with objects rigibody
        Rigidbody2D rigidForForce = other.gameObject.GetComponent < Rigidbody2D > ();

        //Determine left right center of X hit
        if (initialHitPoint.x > (this.transform.position.x + (this.transform.localScale.x / 3)))
        {
            xForce = 1;
        } 
        else if (initialHitPoint.x < (this.transform.position.x - (this.transform.localScale.x / 3)))
        {
            xForce = -1;
        } 
        else
        {
            xForce = 0;
        }

        if (initialHitPoint.y > (this.transform.position.y + (this.transform.localScale.y / 3)))
        {
            yForce = 1;
        } 
        else if (initialHitPoint.y < (this.transform.position.y - (this.transform.localScale.y / 3)))
        {
            yForce = -1;
        } 
        else
        {
            yForce = 0;
        }

        rigidForForce.velocity = new Vector2(xForce * xForceToAdd, yForce * yForceToAdd);
    }
}
```

Comment: okay but it's still not (when I hit the bottom or top of the object) going X=0, Y=1 or X=0, Y=-1 when my player collides with the object I change it to rigidForForce.AddForce(new Vector2(xForce * xForceToAdd, yForce * yForceToAdd), ForceMode2D.Impulse);

Comment: Do more logging on the values `xForce` and `yForce`, check if they have the expected values for the respective situations. Is the mass maybe too high to be lifted up or down? (You can use `ForceMode.VelocityChange` to ignore the mass then)

Comment: thank you but how would I do that? also when you mean mass do you mean by the rigidbody mass?

Comment: Yes, the `Rigidbody2D` has a `mass` and it affects its physics behaviour. For logging, just add a `Debug.Log("xForce: " + xForce + " xForceToAdd: " + xForceToAdd + " yForce: " + yForce + " yForceToAdd: " + yForceToAdd);` before assinging the `.velocity`, then watch the console log.

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I hit the top center of my object I get this in my console log: xForce: 1 xForceToAdd: 100 yForce: 1 yForceToAdd: 100. And when I hit the bottom center of the object I got this at first: xForce: 1 xForceToAdd: 100 yForce: 0 yForceToAdd: 100. Then this after: xForce: 1 xForceToAdd: 100 yForce: 1 yForceToAdd: 100. So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The logic in computing the margins where the hit is being registered is wrong. For example in `this.transform.localScale.y / 3`, the `localScale.y` with probably give you `1.0f`, but what you meant inside the expression `(this.transform.position.y + (this.transform.localScale.y / 3)` is that you want the y-center of the object, plus one-third of it's height. However, `this.transform.localScale.y` will only give you a "multiplier" so to say. In a unscaled object, `transfomr.localScale` will be `1.0`, so you would be adding `transform.position.y + (1.0f / 3)`, which is probably not what you want. You must multipliy this with the actual height of the object to get what you want. This can be done by either relying on the `Sprite` or a `Collider`, e.g. a `BoxCollider2D`. Modified logic (I also divided by `3f` instead of by `3` to make it a more accurate floating point division..):

```
public float xForceToAdd;
public float yForceToAdd;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        //Store the vector 2 of the location where the initial hit happened;
        Vector2 initialHitPoint = new Vector2(other.gameObject.transform.position.x, other.gameObject.transform.position.y);
        float xForce = 0;
        float yForce = 0;

        //Grab our collided with objects rigibody
        Rigidbody2D rigidForForce = other.gameObject.GetComponent < Rigidbody2D > ();

        //Get the width and height of this object by looking up the size of the box collider
        //Alternatively, use constant values here or rely on the Sprite.
        float width = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().size.x;
        float height = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().size.y;

        //Determine left right center of X hit
        if (initialHitPoint.x > (this.transform.position.x + width * (this.transform.localScale.x / 3f)))
            xForce = 1;
        else if (initialHitPoint.x < (this.transform.position.x -  width* (this.transform.localScale.x / 3f)))
            xForce = -1;
        else
            xForce = 0;

        if (initialHitPoint.y > (this.transform.position.y + height * (this.transform.localScale.y / 3f)))
            yForce = 1;
        else if (initialHitPoint.y < (this.transform.position.y - height * (this.transform.localScale.y / 3f)))
            yForce = -1;
        else
            yForce = 0;

        Debug.Log(string.Format("Hit Point X: {0}. Left Boundary: {1} Right Boundary: {2}, xForce = {3}", initialHitPoint.x, (this.transform.position.x  - width*this.transform.localScale.x / 3f), (this.transform.position.x + width * (this.transform.localScale.x / 3f)), xForce));


        rigidForForce.velocity = new Vector2(xForce * xForceToAdd, yForce * yForceToAdd);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but my player still not going X=0, Y=1 when I hit the center (at the top of the object) of the object or going X=0, Y=-1 when I hit the bottom of the object

Comment: I get this in the console log: xForce: 1 xForceToAdd: 100 yForce: 1 yForceToAdd: 100 when I hit the top of the object and thus when I hit the bottom: xForce: 1 xForceToAdd: 100 yForce: -1 yForceToAdd: 100

Comment: See edited code for additional logging the boundary values. However, I suspect that `Vector2 initialHitPoint = new Vector2(other.gameObject.transform.position.x, other.gameObject.transform.position.y);` might be wrong because it doesn't give you the actual hit point, but the other gameobject's coordinate center. See if the coordinates are correct for yourself.

Comment: Thank you for replying back. I'm sorry but I don't know what to do/ What should I change this to.

Comment: You should provide a Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question sothat people can play with the problem and search for an answer themselves.